# Preallocate storage for std::multiset

Tags: c++, allocator, multiset

I want to use preallocated storage for an std::multiset. I have an upper bound on its size known in advance but only at runtime.  Thus, I have written a stack allocator like this one. If the it happens that more than 1 element is requested, it uses the standard allocator as fallback:

```
template<class T>
class PreallocStackAllocator
{
public:
    using Chunk        = std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>;
    using ChunkPointer = Chunk*;
    static_assert(sizeof(Chunk) >= sizeof(T));

    using value_type = T;

    explicit PreallocStackAllocator(size_t capacity)
        : m_freelist{std::make_unique<ChunkPointer[]>(capacity)}
        , m_freelist_end{capacity}
        , m_storage{std::make_unique<Chunk[]>(capacity)}
        , m_capacity{capacity}
    {
        std::generate_n(m_freelist.get(),
                        capacity,
                        [base_address = m_storage.get(), k = static_cast<size_t>(0)]() mutable {
                            auto ret = base_address + k;
                            ++k;
                        return ret;
                    });
    }

    [[nodiscard]] T* allocate(size_t n)
    {
        if(n != 1) [[unlikely]]
        {
            return m_default_allocator.allocate(n);
        }

        assert(m_freelist_end != 0);
        --m_freelist_end;
        return reinterpret_cast<T*>(m_freelist[m_freelist_end]);
    }

    void deallocate(T* ptr, size_t n)
    {
        if(n != 1) [[unlikely]]
        {
            return m_default_allocator.deallocate(ptr, n);
        }

        if(ptr == nullptr) { return; }

        m_freelist[m_freelist_end] = reinterpret_cast<Chunk*>(ptr);
        ++m_freelist_end;
    }

    std::span<size_t const> freelist() const
    {
        return std::span{m_freelist.get(), m_freelist_end};
    }

    size_t capacity() const { return m_capacity; }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<ChunkPointer[]> m_freelist;
    size_t m_freelist_end;
    std::unique_ptr<Chunk[]> m_storage;
    size_t m_capacity;
    [[no_unique_address]] std::allocator<T> m_default_allocator;
};
```

This implementation has two problems:

1. An allocator must be copy-assignable, and the class above is not possible to copy. In particular, a Chunk will contain pointers to other Chunks. Thus, links will be broken if m_storage is reallocated. Do I have to use std::shared_ptr here? Or should copy simply create an allocator with the source capacity, and not care about the current state of the source?
2. When the container is instantiated with a custom allocator, it is created with an allocator, which will allocate space for `capacity` T:s, and also create the free list with `capacity` pointers. However, in reality, we will never allocate T:s, but std::_Rb_tree_node. As far as I understand it, this mapping is done through the rebind meta-function. Anyways, we will now also allocate space for the real content, but we have now wasted space when we created the original allocator. How to fix this?

Comment: (1) I don't think it is safe with all implementation. (2) `std::unique_ptr<T[]> m_storage;` is completely wrong. An allocator manages  and hands out **bytes**, not objects of type `T`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Though the allocator was instantiated with `T = std::_Rb_tree_node<int>`

Comment: It does not matter what it was instantiated with, *you do not construct that type*, with a default constructor or otherwise. You allocate a chunk of memory that is suitable for placement-new of that type, but leave it uninitialised. That's it. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/allocate

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Then, the standard is broken. It is not possible to retrieve a pointer to T without having an existing object. Anything else is undefined behaviour.

Comment: "It is not possible to retrieve a pointer to T without having an existing object". Incorrect. You can cast any suitably aligned pointer to `T*`. There is nothing undefined in it. You cannot dereference that pointer, but this is not required until you placement-new an object in there.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I can use a proxy allocator, whose purpose is to forward the number of elements to allocate:

```
    namespace prealloc_multiset_detail
    {
        template<class T>
        class Allocator: public PreallocStackAllocator<T>
        {
        public:
            template<class CapacityHolder>
            requires requires
            {
                typename CapacityHolder::IsCapacityHolder;
            }
            explicit Allocator(CapacityHolder capacity)
                : PreallocStackAllocator<T>{capacity.capacity()}
            {
            }
        };

        template<class Type>
        class AllocatorProxy
        {
        public:
            using value_type = Type;

            template<class U>
            requires(!std::same_as<U, Type>) struct rebind
            {
                using other = Allocator<U>;
            };

            explicit AllocatorProxy(size_t capacity): m_capacity{capacity} {}

            size_t capacity() const { return m_capacity; }

            struct IsCapacityHolder
            {
            };

        private:
            size_t m_capacity;
        };
    }
```

The set will not be possible to copy, and will be *dead* after a move. But I do not need to copy it, and `insert` on the moved from object is not necessary either in my case.